# как реализовать закрытие попапа с помощью кнопки Esc и при клике вне его

Tags: javascript

не могу понять как правильно реализовать закрытие попапа с помощью кнопки Esc и при клике вне его. Вот ссылка проекта: https://hidison.github.io/mesto/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код и проблемы текстом в вопрос, а не по ссылкам/картинками

Answer (score 1):

В этой ситуации нужно вынести весь слушатель события в отдельную функцию и назначить её слушателем события `keydown`. Во время операции открытия окна вы должны добавить слушатель этого типа события и назначить созданную функцию на него. Когда вы обрабатываете закрытие окна - убрать этот слушатель вызвав [removeEventListener](https://mzl.la/2ZNcQb3) с теми же аргументами, что и при добавлении.

P.S: судя по интерфейсу вы проходите курс обучения Javascript на одной из образовательных платформ. Лучше задавать вопросы по курсу наставникам, а не на stackoverflow - на курсе наверняка сотни подобных вопросов решают и лучше знают, как ожидается решить эту академическую задачку

Answer (score 1):

---

Вам необходимо сделать две функции: открытия и закрытия (это написано в комментарии). Внутри функции открытия вы добавляете необходимый класс попапа и добавляете обработчик на ESC с помощью addEventListener. В функции закрытия, наоборот, удаляете класс и обработчик (с помощью removeEventListener). Колбэком передаете функцию, внутри которой проверяете keyCode (который, кстати говоря, следует вынести в константу) и находите открытое модальное окно, которое уже потом будете передавать аргументом в функцию закрытия, чтобы окно закрылось, и обработчик удалился :)